# What is Ontology Exporter?

Tags: java, ontology, owl

What is ontology exporter?I saw this on [ResearchCyc](http://research.cyc.com/) site.
It mentioned that "An Ontology Exporter that makes it simple to export specified portions of the knowledge base to OWL files".Where can I find this? I want to download it..If anyone know this  plz tell me the link also.

If anybody knows how to separate some portion of knowledge in OpenCyc to OWL files?? Please help me.
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the site to say that it comes bundled with the Cyc download:

> The latest release of Cyc includes:

Did you download OpenCyc to see if it was there?  It might require you to apply for a license.

Comment: Thanks duffymo...I downloaded opencyc but it was not there... I think I'll have to apply for a license..